# Is there a way to move Windows 10 Mail autocmplete DB to Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

A O365 Exchange hosted user is saying that when his Outlook (latest version) was recently setup he lost most of his AutoComplete entries from when he used Win 10 Mail app for about 4 years.

Outlook is set to "Download email for the past" is set to ALL.

Is there a way to copy the Win 10 app autocomplete db to Outlook?

Comment: See if it lives here:  C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.People_8wekyb3d8bbwe\TempState\relevantContactsCache\   Autocomplete for Windows 10 Mail is different than Outlook.

Comment: I looked through the Microsoft Support articles for Autocomplete and the Nirsoft (.net) tools for Autocomplete and I do not see any tools for Windows 10 Mail. The user may need to just let Autocomplete build from their contacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not know much about Mail app, but as I know, AutoComplete list for Exchange email account are synced with the mail server. Please try to re-confirgure this email account by creating and using a new Outlook profile via Control Panel > Mail > Show profile and see if there is any difference.

Besides, it is also suggestd for you to try the MFCMAPI method to see if it could help recover your AutoComplete list. Reference link:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-copy-the-auto-complete-list-to-another-computer-83558574-20dc-4c94-a531-25a42ec8e8f0#copylist